# How do I take an action when a Konva animation ends?

Tags: javascript, html, konvajs

This question is specific to the wheel of fortune example. As a total newbie to javascript, I have managed to change the number of wedges, their colors and labels, but I could not figure out to bind a function to the ending event of the rotation animation. This will be for a small psychology experiment on risk taking behavior and I need to way to determine which wedge came up to the mark at the end of the rotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is directly from the Konva JS documentation ...

```
// the tween has to be created after the node has been added to the layer
var tween = new Konva.Tween({
    node: wheel,
    duration: 4,
    rotation: 360,
    easing: Konva.Easings.BackEaseOut,
    onFinish: function() {
        writeMessage('tween finished!');
    }
});
```

[Konva JS Tween Finish event](https://konvajs.github.io/docs/tweens/Finish_Event.html)